# Building a Perl program to acess a set of data

Tags: arrays, perl

I have to write a Perl program that is able to read the social security baby names for a specific year, and have a person be able to enter a name, and be told weather it is male or female, how many people were born with that name, and where it falls in rank.

So far I have been able to separate the data into two separate arrays based on gender, but have to no idea where to go from here.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open (FILE, "ssbn1898.txt");
print <FILE>;
close (FILE);

my @M_array;
my @F_array; 
open (my $input, "<", 'ssbn1898.txt');
while ( <$input> ) {

    chomp;

    my ( $name, $gender ) = split ( /,/ ); 


    if ( $gender = "M" ) {
        push ( @M_array, $name );
    }
    else {
        push ( @F_array, $name ); 
    }
}
close ( $input );

print 'M: ' . join("\t", @M_array) . "\n"; 
print 'F: ' . join("\t", @F_array) . "\n";
```

http://www.ssa.gov/cgi-bin/popularnames.cgi

This is the data I am working with.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is a little too broad for Stack Overflow's Q&A format (this isn't a great place for spitballing general design ideas). But here's a hint: when you want to do a look up in Perl, usually you should think hash, not array.

Comment: I have to run this program twice, once with a hash and once with an array. @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Is there a better way to go about this then?

Comment: You don't appear to have the skills to accomplish this assignment. Why has it been given to you? Why are you opening the file `ssbn1898.txt` twice?

Answer (score 2):

So far you have 2 arrays for each gender. Now the pending tasks are

- Input: Allow users to input a name
- Output: Male or Female
- Output: Number of people with that name

To take input from user you could do

```
my $userinput = <STDIN>;
```

Then you might need to [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) the $userinput and then check whether the $userinput is in array 1 or array 2. For that you will have to use [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) or [loops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Loop-Control). Doing that you'd be able to find whether name belongs to array with Male names or Females.

```
if (grep /$userinput/, @male_names) {
    print "found $userinput in male list\n";
}
```

Using loop you could do something like below to find total number of people with that name:

```
foreach (@male_names){
   $counter++ if $userinput eq $_;
}
```

---

**PS:** grep returns list, so if you use a scalar you could find number of matches, so you don't have to go for loops.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @male_names = qw(Raj Rohan John Jim Tony Raj Rohan Jim Jim);
my @female_names = qw(Natasha Neha Neha Jasmine Rita Rosy);
my $matches;

my $userinput = <STDIN>;
chomp ($userinput);

if ( $matches = grep /$userinput/, @male_names ) {
    print "found $userinput in male list, count is $matches \n";
}
elsif ( $matches = grep /$userinput/, @female_names ) {
    print "found $userinput in female list, count is $matches \n";
}
else{
    print "Did not find name";
}
```

Comment: Much as I applaud your willingness to help people, providing answers to off-topic questions does encourage more of them to be posted.

Comment: OK Borodin, will make sure not to do that again.

Comment: Okay, but those are my thoughts only. I have no authority here whatsoever